# What does this code do?

Tags: vb.net

```
For Each tag As HtmlTag In tags
    insertTextBuilder.Remove(0, insertTextBuilder.Length)
    insertTextBuilder.AppendFormat("<{0}", tag.Name)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Evaluate answers, and mark the best one as 'accepted'. All you have to do is click the checkmark on the answer. Later, you can also vote up answers that help you. It's all part of the reputation system.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume here that `insertTextBuilder` is a `StringBuilder`.

- take each tag in the collection, type it as `HtmlTag`.

For each tag:

- **Erase the string builder's value.** `Remove()` from index 0 to the length of the stringbuilder's value.
- put in text "`<something`"

You'll be left with the last value in the loop. In other words, do a whole bunch of work, always erase what you previously did, and end up with "`<something`", whatever the LAST tag was in the collection.

Was there a specific line of code, or method call that you were interested in?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see it's going to leave string builder with a < and then the contents of the 'Name' for the last tag in the collection "tags".  Lot of effort for not much content.

Answer (score 0):

**Please spend some time writing a proper question, if you expect people to spend time writing a proper answer.**

It looks like it clears the insertTextBuilder contents (0 to length)
then it adds the text < and htmlTag's name (A, H1, etc) "

It does this in a loop, so you'll just end up with "<(last tags name)" which probably isn't the desired functionality.